# XML file in layout folder error: can not be resolved or is not a field

Tags: java, android

I'm using Eclipse with Android SDK. I have added a XML file in the layout folder called `voice_recog.xml` by *File > New > Other > Android > Android Xml File*.

On this code line:

```
setContentView(R.layout.voice_recog);
```

I'm getting the following error:

> voice_recog.xml can not be resolved or is not a field

Thus, I think it is not seeing the file I created even though it's in the layout folder. How is this caused and how can I solve it?

Comment: That's a compilation error. Shouldn't there be quotes around the file name?

Comment: try to clean the project and rebuild it.

Comment: file is located in the layout folder in res. I have read if a file in adb does not have permission than r.java is not created.. ??

Comment: I tried to clean with no luck, also had auto build in clean run after clean and still nogo..

Comment: Does the R file get generated? Sounds like there's something else causing the R file not to get generated properly. Make sure to check the "Problems" view in Eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

On the top of the file, there will be an import statement `import Android.R`. Remove this import statement and hover over the "R" of `setContentView(R.layout.voice_recog);` It will give u an option to import the R file referenced in ur project. Import it and the error will not be there.